# Powershell On Target Machine and Deployment Group

Tags: powershell, tfs, deployment

I can use the Powershell on Target machine task fine from an agent phase.  In a Deployment group phase however, I'm not so lucky.  The Powershell task gets called for each server in the group as expected, but it doesn't use the name of the server from the group.  The Powershell task requires a Machine name that I don't know until the release runs.

[image: Task Input]

What do I put in the task for machine name so it will pick up the name of the deployment group server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a deployment group, you don't need to use PowerShell on Target Machines -- it's **already running** in the context of that machine. Just use a PowerShell task.

You only need to use PowerShell on Target Machines if you're running on the build agent and need to kick off a script on a different machine.

Comment: Well, that makes perfect sense now that you pointed it out. Sometimes you try to force that square peg into the round hole. Thanks.